# Sort multiple XML by element value from another XML

Tags: sorting, merge, xslt-2.0

Basically what I'm trying to here is to merge and sort a multiple XML by a value of an element in a reference XML using XSLT.

```
> <xsl:variable name="refXml"
> select="document(concat(replace($refXmlTemp,'^file:',''),'/ref.xml'))"/>
> 
> 

> <xsl:for-each select="for $x in
> collection(string-join(($inputDir,'select=*.xml;recurse=yes;on-error=fail'),'?'))
> return 
>                         (if (matches($refXml/root/descendant-or-self::issue/id[normalize-space(.)=normalize-space($x/art/item/id)]/number,'\w+')
> and matches($x/art/item/title,'\w+')) then saxon:discard-document($x) 
>                         else ())">

> <xsl:sort select="$refXml/root/descendant-or-self::issue/id[normalize-space(.)=/art/item/id]/following-sibling::number"/>
```

The snippet above merged all the input XML but it was not sorted.

It seems that the XSLT `xsl:sort`function will only take an effect if it will be pointed at a value inside the XML that's currently processing.

Please advise on how could i get to use the ref.xml as a reference in sorting.

Here's a sample input of ref.xml:

```
<root>   
 <issue>
    <id>wlu-101</id>
    <number>1</number>   
 </issue>
 <issue>
    <id>wlu-143</id>
    <number>2</number>
 </issue>
 <issue-group>
    <issue>
      <id>wlu-144</id>
      <number>3</number>
    </issue>
    <issue-group>
      <issue>
        <id>wlu-185</id>
        <number>4</number>
      </issue>
    </issue-group>
</issue-group> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<xsl:sort select="$refXml/root/descendant-or-self::issue/id[normalize-space(.)=/art/item/id]/following-sibling::number"/>` with

```
<xsl:sort select="key('ref', /art/item/id, $refXml)/number"/>
```

after defining

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="issue" use="normalize-space(id)"/>
```

As an alternative use `<xsl:sort select="$refXml//issue[normalize-space(id)=current()/art/item/id]/number"/>`.

Comment: Thank you Martin but when I tried your suggested code, it doesn't sort the way it supposed to; it looks like doesn't have any changes on xml.

Comment: Can you try to reduce the problem to a minimum of three or four input files you want to process in sorted order and show us the samples, reduced to the minimum to demonstrate the problem? I am afraid it is not possible to tell from only your XSLT code snippets where things fail, we need to see some sample data to establish which key or path is wrong.

Comment: woot! It seems to be my fault why it doesn't work on my first try, sorry. However, the descendant-or-self wasn't able to work with the <xsl:key> how could we use it to get the value of number? would it be possible?

Comment: @Viin, I have made some changes that should work with your input data.

Comment: you're the best @Martin!! Thank you!